# T-SQL (Azure) table gives double results

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I am trying to get a list of all the id_user and the amount of creditRecieved and the amount of creditUsed, I actually would like to add a third option that mentions the left over if any. If creditReceived is bigger as creditUsed. But the first part now doubles the outputs so I started following an explanation here on StackOverflow, but I can't get it to work.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.UserPurchase.CreditUsed,
    dbo.UserCredit.CreditRecieved

FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(dbo.UserPurchase.creditUsed) AS CreditUsed
    FROM dbo.UserPurchase
)

dbo.UserPurchase LEFT JOIN

(
    SELECT SUM(dbo.UserCredit.creditRecieved) AS CreditRecieved
    FROM dbo.UserCredit
)

dbo.UserCredit ON dbo.UserPurchase.id_user = dbo.UserCredit.id_user
```

The data comes from these two tables

TABLE dbo.UserCredit

```
id          id_user     creditRecieved PurchasePrice
----------- ----------- -------------- -------------
1           1           150            750
2           1           25             100
3           2           65             15
```

TABLE dbo.UserPurchase

```
id          id_user     creditUsed  date
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           175         NULL
2           2           3           NULL
3           2           2           NULL
```

I would like to have the following result

```
id_user     CreditRecieved CreditUsed  CreditLeftOver
----------- -------------- ----------- --------------
1           175            175         0
2           65             5           60
```

Comment: please post expected result,actual result ,posting ddl,dml also helps a lot

Comment: its not working at all it results in error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try querying each table separately:

```
SELECT users.id_user, coalesce(credit.received, 0) received,
  coalesce(purchase.used, 0) Used, coalesce(credit.received, 0) - coalesce(purchase.used, 0) LeftOver, coalesce(purchase.purchaseCount, 0) purchaseCount
FROM 
(
  select distinct id_user from dbo.UserCredit
  union
  select distinct id_user from dbo.UserPurchase
) users
left outer join 
(
  select id_user, sum(creditRecieved) received from dbo.UserCredit group by id_user
) credit
on users.id_user = credit.id_user
left outer join 
(
  select id_user, sum(creditUsed) used, count(1) purchaseCount from dbo.UserPurchase group by id_user
) purchase
on users.id_user = purchase.id_user
```

- Please note that there is a typo in `CreditRecieved`. It should be `CreditReceived`.

Comment: It works perfectly fine, thank you, could you perhaps elaborate a bit more please? Why would they not load the actual tables in the design section in management studio? In the case i would like to extend it :)

Comment: Just as a quick question how would i be able to add the count of a user that has purchased something (used credit)?

Comment: I updated the answer to have a counter. Now about your first question, I'm kind of busy right now. I'll try to elaborate more later. Sorry :(  But the main point is that you need to first group the data individually and then query both tables already grouped. About not loading in management studio, it's probably because I had to create a subquery (`... from ( select ...`).

Comment: thanks, i found out, reading some web pages how to get the counter, however i am stuck now with a new problem, based on your input: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589810/t-sql-azure-only-shows-2-results-instead-of-3 Perhaps you got a very simple solution. Loving the Coalesce by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the creditUsed and creditRecieved (typo on your end?) summed up by id_user? This would be the query:

```
SELECT p.id_user, SUM(p.creditUsed), SUM(u.creditRecieved)
  FROM dbo.UserCredit u
  LEFT JOIN dbo.UserPurchase p ON p.id_user = u.id_user
 GROUP BY p.id_user
```

Comment: that is correct, i started with this but however the result is doubled

Comment: than add the keyword DISTINCT after the SELECT.

Comment: Does not change anything, still double results

Comment: if you execute DISTINCT, there can't be double results. Please post your result.

Comment: those are 2 id_users: 1 and 2. so how is it double?

Comment: the amounts are doubled :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT 
    C.id_user,
    C.CreditRecieved,
    P.CreditUsed,
    C.CreditRecieved - P.CreditUsed CreditLeftOver
FROM 
    (SELECT id_user, SUM(creditRecieved) CreditRecieved FROM UserCredit GROUP BY id_user) C 
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT id_user, SUM(creditUsed) CreditUsed FROM UserPurchase GROUP BY id_user) P ON C.id_user = P.id_user
```