# T-SQL (Azure) Only shows 2 results instead of 3

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Hi i am extending a query and i have the following problem, i have in a table 3 users and they are connected (joined) with other tables, now in these tables the user can or can not have data, depending on their actions.

```
SELECT 

COALESCE (credit.received, 0) AS CreditReceived, 
COALESCE (purchase.used, 0) AS CreditUsed, 
COALESCE (purchase.NumberOfPurchase, 0) AS NumberOfPurchase, 
COALESCE (credit.received, 0) - COALESCE (purchase.used, 0) AS UserCredit,

dbo.[User].id_user, 
dbo.[User].name, 
dbo.[User].town, 
dbo.[User].country

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id_user
FROM dbo.UserCredit
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT id_user
FROM dbo.UserPurchase) AS users 

INNER JOIN
dbo.[User] ON users.id_user = dbo.[User].id_user 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT        
id_user, 
SUM(creditRecieved) AS received
FROM            
dbo.UserCredit AS UserCredit_1
GROUP BY id_user) AS credit 
ON users.id_user = credit.id_user 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT        
id_user, 
SUM(creditUsed) AS used,
COUNT(creditUsed) AS NumberOfPurchase
FROM            
dbo.UserPurchase AS UserPurchase_1
GROUP BY id_user) AS purchase 
ON users.id_user = purchase.id_user
```

The information comes from these tables;

TABLE dbo.user

```
id_user     name        town           country
----------- ----------- -------------- -------------
1           George      New York       USA
2           Lucas       San Diego      GB
3           Steven      San Fran       Germany
```

TABLE dbo.UserCredit

```
id          id_user     creditRecieved PurchasePrice
----------- ----------- -------------- -------------
1           1           150            750
2           1           25             100
3           2           65             15
```

TABLE dbo.UserPurchase

```
id          id_user     creditUsed  date
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           175         NULL
2           2           3           NULL
3           2           2           NULL
```

What i get is only the result of the two first user_id's and the third one (steven) is not shown in the results, i guess it is because the id's dont exist in the other two tables, but that i was hoping would be fixed with the COALESCE and the four of them would be set to 0. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: coalesce will NOT manufacture a row that doesn't exist. If you want to return all users you would need to change your INNER JOINS to LEFT JOINS. Of course this is only a guess because you didn't provide all the tables here.

Comment: They are all there now since you removed one.

Comment: yes that was a copy mistake, these are the tables that give the error result, so i am not making a row that does not exist, it does exist in the user table but the user has not bought something therefor the id does not appear in the userPurchase table. So how do i do that? The LEFT does not do the trick.

Comment: Look closely at your data. Your primary table for this query is the derived table selecting all id_user from UserCredit and UserPurchase. The id_user 3 is NOT in either of those tables.

Comment: ok trying to change it, but can't figure out the joins, i updated the question with some good based on your and @Matt Hartman input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By replacing the first DISTINCT with the dbo.[User] instead of the dbo.UserCredit it gave me the right results; All users in the overview with credit or no credit, thanks to the COALESCE :)

```
SELECT 

COALESCE (credit.received, 0) AS CreditReceived, 
COALESCE (purchase.used, 0) AS CreditUsed, 
COALESCE (purchase.NumberOfPurchase, 0) AS NumberOfPurchase, 
COALESCE (credit.received, 0) - COALESCE (purchase.used, 0) AS UserCredit,

dbo.[User].id_user, 
dbo.[User].name, 
dbo.[User].town, 
dbo.[User].country

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id_user
FROM dbo.[User]
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT id_user
FROM dbo.UserPurchase) AS users 

INNER JOIN
dbo.[User] ON users.id_user = dbo.[User].id_user 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT        
id_user, 
SUM(creditRecieved) AS received
FROM            
dbo.UserCredit AS UserCredit_1
GROUP BY id_user) AS credit 
ON users.id_user = credit.id_user 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT        
id_user, 
SUM(creditUsed) AS used,
COUNT(creditUsed) AS NumberOfPurchase
FROM            
dbo.UserPurchase AS UserPurchase_1
GROUP BY id_user) AS purchase 
ON users.id_user = purchase.id_user
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the derived table "users." It doesn't contain all the userid's and is unnecessary. Remove that and left join to your user table instead and it should work.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: It won't let me comment on the question.

Comment: Try fixing your left joins by using the derived table alias in your on clause, i.e. "ON credit.user_id = " I'd also use an alias for your first table dbo.[User], but I don't think it's necessary.